# Android onLocationChanged when distance is changed OR time elapsed

Tags: android, geolocation, location, google-play-services

I need to refresh the screen by making a server call when either the location has changed OR when 30 minutes has passed.
I have followed the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) (using Google Play Services API) but also the one [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

However none of them is working; I'm trying to change my location from one side of the planet to the other, and I still see the the server call isn't made.

The way I'm configuring my location request object is:

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(Constants.MINIMUM_DISTANCE_LOCATION_UPDATE);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.LOCATION_INTERVAL_UPDATE);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
```

Is this the right way to make this work, or should I try a different approach?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I assume that you have implemented `LocationListner` , is call back not coming to `onLocationChanged()` ?

Comment: @Satty I did, and no, it's not coming back

Comment: can you share more details of code ?